# populate JQuery datetimepicker with persian(jalaali) calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, datetimepicker, momentjs

I want to use [JQuery datetimepicker](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) with persian calendar.
Since it's not officially supported, I'm trying to do it using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and [moment-jalaali.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/).

I managed to get the input to change to persian date.

I mean upon clicking on day 6th of December 2014 the input would change to "1393/9/15" which is the same date in persian calendar.

and this is what I've done so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment-jalaali.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Date.parseDate = function( input, format ){
        return moment(input,format).toDate();
    };
    Date.prototype.dateFormat = function( format ){
        return moment(this).format(format);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'jYYYY/jM/jD - H:m',
            lang: 'fa'
        });
    });
</script>
```

But calendar is still showing gregorian calendar. and adding the "lang" option to datepicker, only changes the language of calendar.

I have to populate the calendar with persian calendar and I have absolutely no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a long time I found [this repo](https://github.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker) very useful.

this is the normal jquery ui datepicker:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date-input').datepicker();
});
```

```css
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="date" class="date-input">
```

which can be modified to show jalali calendar with including [bootstrap-datepicker.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker/master/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js) instead of jquery.ui.js.

BUT: since this repo wanted to add twitter bootstrap theme for the datepicker, some of class names in the datepicker was changed to work with twitter bootstrap theme. But that wasn't what I wanted. I wanted to be able to use jquery ui themes. so I forked the repo and and edited the class names back to the jquery ui original names.

Just include these files ([jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Taxellool/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker/master/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker.min.js) & [datepicker.fa.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Taxellool/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker/master/datepicker.fa.min.js)) and any jquery-ui theme can be applied.

the result is like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date-input').datepicker();
});
```

```css
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Taxellool/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker/master/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Taxellool/jquery-ui-jalali-datepicker/master/datepicker.fa.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="date" class="date-input"/>
```

Comment: Hello, your links not working. Would you please check and edit them.